# What is the logic behind == returning false [toString()] when two reference variables are referring to same Object having same hashCode?

Tags: java, equals, tostring, hashcode, object-class

What is the logic behind `==` returning false when two reference variables are referring to same Object having same hash code values?

```
public class One {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        One o = new One();
        One o1 = o; 
        System.out.println(o.toString());                                       
        System.out.println(o1.toString());                                      
        System.out.println(o.hashCode());                                       
        System.out.println(o1.hashCode());                                      
        
        // Why does it print false ?
        System.out.println(o.toString()==o1.toString());    // false                    
        System.out.println(o.hashCode()==o1.hashCode());    // true                 
        System.out.println(o.equals(o1));                   // true
                            
        System.out.println(o.toString().hashCode()==o.toString().hashCode());   // true 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The line with

```
System.out.println(o.toString()==o1.toString());    // false
```

has a `toString()`. Each `toString()` creates a new String Object, which are different Objects that have their own memory locations. So the `==` actually checks the memory addresses between those new String Objects.

Always compare strings with [`String#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), not with `==`.

Comment: Good Answer. You might want to add a mention of `hashCode` returning an `int`, which as a primitive has no issue with comparing reference versus comparing value. In contrast, `toString` returning a `String` involves references as `String` is an object, not a primitive. In other words, explain why `o.hashCode()==o1.hashCode()` is a non-issue whereas `o.toString()==o1.toString()` is a problem.

Comment: @Basil Bourque I am beginner, please excuse me. Printing RV of o and o1 leads to same output, which is Fully Qualified Name @ hashCode value of the Object in HEX format. When o and o1, prints same output, how is it false ?

Comment: The contents of the string are the same, but each toString() generates a new memory location for the string. Then since Strings are an object, using `==` compares the references (memory locations) rather than the contents of the string.

Answer (score 1):

`==` sign checks the memory addresses of objects being compared. In your case, `toString()` method creates two different `String` objects stored in two different places. That's why you get `false` when you try to compare them.

 On the other hand, `equals()` checks the equality of contents of the objects. For your own data types, you should override this method to use it. 
`hashCode` is some sort of a unique identification number for the **contents** of the objects. That is to say, objects that are equal to each other must return the same hashCode.